# Entity Framework 6 + Code First + Oracle 11g

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, oracle11g, code-first

Is there any way to create 100% the Oracle11g database using EF Code First?
And how to trace the Oracle query in SaveChanges?

Comment: [EF 4.2 and Oracle](http://dotnetspeak.com/2012/01/oracle-odp-and-entity-framework-code-first-4-2)
But seems not to be 100% supported by Oracle.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use third party to have a code first solution with oracle and ef 6 one of this providers is DevArt you can read more about the support here [Ef6 in devart](http://blog.devart.com/entity-framework-6-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-sqlite-and-salesforce.html)

And about the log you can enable log in ef6 as is explained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/data/dn469464

Answer (score 1):

Try oracle odac 12c release 3, but only support EF6 code first.

Answer (score 1):

I know its 2015 and you are looking for 11g . But its now available on 11g if still interested . 
  [Try this link](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/CodeFirst/index.html) which belong to official oracle documentation for code first but on 12g onwards