# Using Oracle with EF code first

Tags: database, oracle, entity-framework, ef-code-first, odp.net

I wrote a project with `EF code first 6` and  `SQL Server 2008R2` for a company, Now the company wants to switch its DB to `Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0`,

- How could I find appropriate version of `ODP.NET` or `ODAC`?
- Could I use `ODAC 12c` or any other versions for `Oracle 10g` or each `Oracle` version has its own `ODAC` version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of **[Can you use Microsoft Entity Framework with Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82644/can-you-use-microsoft-entity-framework-with-oracle)** also **[Entity Framework 6 + Code First + Oracle 11g](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480921/entity-framework-6-code-first-oracle-11g)** and **[Entity Framework 6 (5) connection to Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299654/entity-framework-6-5-connection-to-oracle)**

Answer (score 2):

You could just rely on the last version of odp.net managed driver but beware that some features might not be available on your 10g (like APPLY)

***Changes in Oracle Data Provider for .NET Release 12.1 in ODAC 12c Release 2***
*Support for APPLY Keyword
Language Integrated Query (LINQ) is a .NET querying language. At runtime, LINQ is translated into native database SQL before it can query the database. In some circumstances, LINQ uses the non-standard APPLY keyword in its SQL translation for retrieving lateral views. Oracle Database and ODP.NET support the APPLY keyword in Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1) to more fully support LINQ*

On the other hand oracle has no official support for EF code first ([link](https://twitter.com/dandohotaru/status/448829988394242048))
and moreover odp.net is not compatible with EF6 so you'll have to target EF5 for now ([link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2565269))

At the end of the day you'll need to rely on either of the two

- Entity Framework 5 and Odp.Net (free but without official support for code first)
- Entity Framework 6 and Devart dot connect (payed but full code first support)

As far as I am concerned I've successfully implemented solutions based on a scenario as the one bellow

- Oracle database (11g)
- Odp.net managed driver via nuget (121.1.1)
- Odac client installation is not required
- Entity Framework 5