# Using Oracle with EF5 code first

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, exception

I wrote a project with EF5 code first (MVC 4) and an Oracle Database, I followed the Oracle procedures (and tips from here), after several attempts, impossible to make everything work.

Here that I have:

**Packages :**

```
<package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="odp.net.x86" version="112.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

**Web.config :**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name='Context' connectionString="DATA SOURCE=**.**.**.**:1521/FOLIO;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;Connection Lifetime=10;USER ID=*****;Password=*****;" providerName='Oracle.DataAccess.Client' />
</connectionStrings>

<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
        <add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

**My DataTable mapping :**

```
Folio
{
[Table("USERS", Schema = "FOLIO")]
public class Users
{
        [Key]
        [Column("USR_CODE")]
        public string USR_CODE { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("USR_NAME")]
        public string USR_NAME { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("USR_FIRSTNAME")]
        public string USR_FIRSTNAME { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("USR_INITIALS")]
        public string USR_INITIALS { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("USR_PASSWORD")]
        public string USR_PASSWORD { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I still have the same exception :

"An error occurred while accessing data"

Here is the details :

```
    [DalException: Une erreur est survenue lors de l'accès aux données]
   Portfolio.Oracle.Service.BaseService.ManageError(Exception ex) in c:\Users\FEVRE\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Portfolio.Oracle.Mvc\Portfolio.Oracle.Service\BaseService.cs:88
   Portfolio.Oracle.Service.ProjectService.GetProjects() in c:\Users\FEVRE\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Portfolio.Oracle.Mvc\Portfolio.Oracle.Service\ProjectService.cs:22
   Portfolio.Oracle.Mvc.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in c:\Users\FEVRE\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Portfolio.Oracle.Mvc\Portfolio.Oracle.Mvc\Controllers\HomeController.cs:32
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +101
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +211
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +223
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +24
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9514928
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I do not understand, I can not find the problem (EF ?)

I saw it is possible here : [Using Oracle with EF code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718538/using-oracle-with-ef-code-first/24389938#24389938)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is not compatible with Code First. A Beta of EF6 client for oracle with Code first will be released this summer